# タグ情報の上位ユーザーに関する情報が更新されていない

Tags: バグ, サポート, 完了

[emeditor](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emeditor) タグに関して情報を知りたかったため、当該タグ情報ページを閲覧していました。以下のスクリーンショットは 2 月 28 日 21 時時点での [emeditor](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emeditor) タグのタグ情報ページのスクリーンショットです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この画像の上位ユーザーには誰も載っていません。これは、[emeditor](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emeditor) タグに投稿を行ったユーザーの中でプラス投票を得たユーザーが存在しないことを示しています。しかし、過去 1 か月間の間にプラス票を獲得した回答は幾つかあり、これらが上位回答ユーザーに反映されていないことは不自然だと感じています。画像下部に「日次更新」と書かれていることから、掲載されているデータは毎日更新されていると認識しています。

- [EmEditor Professionalで記号の数字での昇順、降順の並べ替え方法をお願いいたします｡](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/74059/32986)
- [UnicodeをURLエンコードした文字列を表示したとき、変換後の文字列をコピーできない場合がある](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/73780/32986)

このタグ情報ページの動作は単なる反映の遅れでしょうか、それともバグでしょうか？もし反映の遅れであった場合は、ここに反映されるデータは（日次ではなく）いつ収集・更新されますか？

Comment: I'll add this to be addressed as part of our regular bug duty rotation. Thanks for the report!（こちらを通常のバグデューティローテーションに追加し対処いたします。ご報告ありがとうございます！ ）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

問題が修正されました :

シンプルに申し上げますと、これらの統計は毎晩更新されますが、それを実行するジョブにはいくつかのステップがバンドルされています。上位の回答の更新はステップ #2 であり、ステップ #1 は無関係の理由で失敗していました。エラーが修正され、タグの使用が期待どおりに更新されています。ご報告ありがとうございます！その他にも関連する問題が発生した場合にはどうぞお知らせください。

[image]